# Wordpress Jquery Cycle2 plugin not working

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using Cycle2 plugin in my Wordpress homepage, but it won't work. First I tried using the class "cycle-slideshow", but I only get this on the console log:

> [cycle2] --c2 init--

Now I'm trying to use the API, but still only get the log message, no slider. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery( '#home_slider' ).cycle();
            });
            </script>

            <div id='home_slider'>
                                <div class='home_slide'>
                    <div class='slide_tit'>Proyectos</div>
                    <div class='slide_resumen'>Esta es la descripcion</div>
                    <img src='http://localhost/laben/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/header03.jpg'/>
                </div>
                            <div class='home_slide'>
                    <div class='slide_tit'>Investigación</div>
                    <div class='slide_resumen'>Las principales Áreas de Investigación del Laboratorio de Envases de la Universidad de Santiago de Chile están relacionadas con Envases Activos, Interacción Envase/Alimento, Nanotecnología y Envases Biodegradables. Es preciso indicar que todas estas no son áreas independientes sino más bien áreas que se complementan totalmente entre sí.</div>
                    <img src='http://localhost/laben/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/header01.jpg'/>
                </div>
                            <div class='home_slide'>
                    <div class='slide_tit'>Servicios</div>
                    <div class='slide_resumen'>Esta es la descripcion</div>
                    <img src='http://localhost/laben/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/header02.jpg'/>
                </div>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery do you have included?

Comment: Post that as an answer, then when it lets you, accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Fixed it. It supports images by default, so to make a slider out of other elements needs to be specified a selector:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( '#home_slider' ).cycle({ slides: '.home_slide' });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The Developer should really clarify these requirements with his example. Such nice plugins, cycle and cycle2, but had to hunt fixes down to work with cycle2. Thanks for pointing this out @edoher

Answer (score 0):

> functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'twentyseventeen-global', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/global.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
```

> js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#slider').cycle({
    slides: '.article',
    fx: 'scrollHorz'
});
</script>
```